# Using Core Animation In SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit, core-animation

I've been prototyping some behaviour by using Keynote and I was wondering if it's possible to use Core Animation animations in a SpriteKit (OS X) app. I can't really find any info that suggests this is possible or not possible. Hopefully this is not a dumb question. If it is possible, what steps are necessary to set it up in a SpriteKit project to do something like an "anvil drop" animation on a sprite?

Comment: Why do you even need to use Core Animation in the first place when in fact you can animate frames with SpriteKit?

Comment: That's true, but then you have to be able to capture the various frames right? I just figured that it might be faster to use Core Animation.

Comment: What is the texture atlas for?

Comment: What I'm saying is that I'd have to create each frame for the texture atlas and I'm not much of an artist. I know how to use a texture atlas, but that's not my question.

Comment: Core animation offers a lot more flexibility than sprite kit actions, when it comes to timing functions etc. It's not at all a dumb question. OP, do you have a reference for the kind of animation you want? Is it like a drop with a slight bounce, like a heavy dense object? You can set up an SKAction sequence which would mimic a keyframed animation.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for the response. Yeah, there's a good amount of stuff in that framework. I've created pretty complicated SKActions in the past. I can definitely recreate some of the core animation animations with SKActions, but it requires exactly that; complicated action sequences. Not to mention that some of them would require some sort of particle emitter. If this is the only way, then I guess I'll have to bite the bullet and cobble them together. So, there's no way to tie Core Animations into SK?

Comment: Yes, you can use CA Keyframe Animations and Explicit Animation techniques within Sprite Kit. You have CA at your full disposal whilst using Sprite Kit. Much of Sprite Kit is just wrappers around parts of Core Animation.

Comment: Any resources that you can point me to? Or even better, can you demonstrate, through code, how to do create any of the animation effects in obj C? I don't know where to start. I've been scouring the web for info on how to set this up.